# Why this share images not work with all mobile devices only some?

Tags: java, android, image, share

***share image code***
I would like to find an example of code which will allow me to share an image through the Android Intent, ACTION_SEND that is compatible with the largest number of Android devices.

My code as it stands looks as follows:

```
  public void onClickShare(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/png");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(SavedCardActivity.sharingcardpath)));
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"), 1);
    }
```

At the moment, this code will not work with all mobile devices just some mobile devices,  especially devices with android versions **6.0 7.0 7.1 8.0**, i don't know if this code is correct or not.

I want code like that work with all devices.

Comment: Can you give us more context here? What exactly are you trying to do? What versions of Android does it work on? What versions have you shown it fails on? What kind of error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

If targetSdkVersion is higher than 24, then FileProvider is used to grant access.

Create an xml file named *provider_paths.xml* in *res\xml*, with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
 </paths>
```

Then you need to add a Provider in AndroidManifest.xml inside your application tag

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
 </provider>
```

Now get your photos path like this:

```
final File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "/path/filename.png");
```

Now get Photo URI like this:

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(SavedCardActivity.this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                photoFile);
```

And to share, use this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
        } else {
            final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
        }
```